# how to assign Post to User through user_id and author_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I have a table users. they can post records in different users profiles, so for every post I have user_id (in whose profile a post was written) and autor_id (who wrote the post).
Please could you help me - which relations should be to connect posts model with users twice?
Now I have such code:

user.rb

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
```

post.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :author, :class_name => "User"
```

it does not let me call **@post.author.name**, as I see I connected it wrong to the users model. Please could you help me?

Comment: `@post.user.name` try this

Comment: post.user.name works for me, but I need also post.author.name which would use author_id from posts model to find a user from users model with equal user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your associations are wrong..they should be like this

`belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'author_id'`

And now you can call it as

`@post.author.name`

There is a difference between `belongs_to` and  `has_one` and that is you should define belongs_to when that table is containing foreign key.

Comment: yes, I tried that, but it shows me user by user_id when I call @post author.name.
The idea is that it should show user by user_id when I call post.user.name and user by author_id (from users table by user_id) when I call post.author.id

Answer (score 1):

finally I resolved the problem:

user.rb

```
has_many :posts, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "user_id"
has_many :records, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "author_id"
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_id'
belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'author_id'
```

authors put records, users get posts written by authors. Thank you, @test